# Can cookies be shared between subdomains over SSL on different servers?

Tags: security, ssl, cookies

We are evaluating feasibility of the following solution for Single Sign On.

Scenario.
Website domain. https://www.example.com

- [SSL using multi-server wildcard certificate]
- Hosted on Server 1.

Other portal. https://portal.example.com

- [SSL using the same certificate (multi-server wildcard certificate)]
- Hosted on Server 2.

Solution:
The intention is to share a cookie between the www.example.com and the portal.example.com subdomains, however, for this to work the SSL protocol needs to satisfy the following requirements:

- Continue to block Man-in-the-middle attacks.
- Encrypt/Decrypt in the same manner for both Server 1 and Server 2. So that they can get the same information from the cookie.

Question is: Is there any limitations in terms of private keys or the SSL protocol perse that will make the solution above not feasible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your solution will work and will mitigate most MITM attacks provided the CA that your certificates are purchased from are trusted by the client browsers.

If the cookie is set with domain `example.com` it will be shared between `www.example.com` and `portal.example.com`. It is also advisable to set the Secure flag to make sure it cannot be transmitted over plain HTTP. I am assuming both `www.example.com` and `portal.example.com` both have a server-side mechanism to validate the cookie value to authorise each request.

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3) states:

> The Domain attribute specifies those hosts to which the cookie will be
> sent.  For example, if the value of the Domain attribute is
> "example.com", the user agent will include the cookie in the Cookie
> header when making HTTP requests to example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and
> [www.corp.example.com](http://www.corp.example.com).

The old RFC 2109 specified that you needed a `.` before the domain, however 6265 overrides this. This means if you want to share cookies and make it compatible with *very old* browsers you should set the cookie with domain `.example.com` rather than `example.com`. There is nothing to lose by doing the former as newer browsers will simply ignore the dot.

In your solution, both Server 1 and Server 2 will receive and be able to decrypt the cookie. Note there is not requirement for both servers to have the same certificate - they will both decrypt the SSL session independently using their installed private keys (or rather a shared symmetric key that is transmitted using their installed private keys - to be precise).

However, using a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com` will be cheaper as the same certificate can be installed on both servers.

Comment: What if the two servers in the question above use different SSL certificates,   will web browsers still pass the secure cookie on requests to both servers?

Comment: @MarkRoper: Yes, if the browser trusts both certificates, the cookie will be sent. Remember, all the Secure flag does is prevent the cookie from being sent over plain HTTP connections. If the underlying SSL/TLS connection is possible by the browser, and the cookie domain and path match, the browser will send the cookie with the request.

Comment: This is what I thought, but we have not actually set this up yet, thanks!